# Discord Bot can't find embeds in messages

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I have a message with a single embed in it, when using

```
message.embeds
```

I get nothing back, the length of it is 0 and when printing the list there's nothing there. If I try to refer to anything in the list I get an out of range error, because there's nothing there obviously.

I can still read message content itself, if there is raw text there. So my question is, am I going about getting the embeds in the wrong way? If not, is there a way to just get the raw text of a message and sort of go around the embed?

Thank you!

Added below is a picture of one of the messages I am trying to read, as you can see it clearly has an embed :

[image]

For further context here is the full code

```
async def on_message(message):
      if message.channel.id in channels:
           print(str(message.embeds))
           #or any other reference to an embed in the message, none of the work
```

Comment: The message won't have embeds if it returns a length of 0.

Comment: It does have embeds, I am the one sending it and I am 100% including an embed with it. I am also trying to read embeds in other servers, and they're clearly embeds, denoted by the line on the left of the text and entire text being indented.

Comment: Those are not embeds. Embeds are dark and in a box sort of thing. Many bot's help commands are used in embeds. Try using those.

Comment: I put a picture, can you take a look? I am 99% sure that is an embed. If it's not, what on earth is it because mesage.content returns nothing as well

Comment: Yes, that's an embed. (I thought you were talking about quotes). Are you sure you're reading that message? Try making sure that the IDs are the same.

Comment: Yeah, like I said if I put just regular text in there then I can read that via message.content it just won't send the embeded and won't register that the embeded is there.

Comment: Could you show what you have?

Comment: More could would help, where are you trying to use this? Have you tried doing this manually with a message id? how are you getting the message? more info would help

Comment: Are you sure you're not talking about an attachment? Images and video can be attached to the message without being an embed or taking space in the content.

Comment: @Levi_OP it's not an attachment no, definitely just an embed. Also if anyone is curious, it's likely to do with it being a 'self bot' using my own discord token, not a traditional bot.

Comment: @DoesntEven, take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67341709/12451222) answer. Discord stopped allowing self-bots from working now.

Comment: @ceres Yeah that was the case. It worked upon using an older version of discord.py, rather annoying as self bots are very useful in situations where someone isn't going to let a regular bot into the server.

Answer (score 1):

`message.embeds` returns a list of embeds in the message  [[docs]](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Message.embeds)

To get the contents of the Embeds in the message, you could do:

```
embeds = message.embeds
for embed in embeds:
  print(embed.title)
  print(embed.description)
```

or this if there is only one embed in the message

```
embeds = message.embeds
embed = embeds[0]
print(embed.title)
print(embed.description)
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't quite understand your question, maybe I'm just dumb, but it seems like your having a bit of a problem with embeds. Maybe if I show you an example you will understand.

```
@client.command()
async def Embed(ctx):
    embed=discord.Embed(title="Title")
    embed.add_field(name="Field Name", value="Field Text", inline=False)
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

I hope this helped, if you want to ask any further questions please feel free to comment on this message! Thanks,