# Discord API "soft-ban" for Selfbot? It can only read its own messages

Tags: discord, discord.py

So today, all of a sudden, my Discord Selfbot stopped working. It has been running for weeks without any issue. All it does is monitoring the bot alerts from other channels and notify me if certain conditions are met.

Basically the problem is that when I `print(message.content)` I get empty string, and when I `print(message.embeds)` I get an empty list. This happens for any message that isn't sent by myself. Basically I can pull any message from any channel, but if it's not sent by me, I will see it empty. I can still `print(message)` and see its ID, author, etc., but can't retrieve the content/embeds.

I thought it was some sort of soft-ban from the Discord API (account didn't receive any warning and works normally), but then tryed to make a new account and got the same issue. I'm so confused and can't find out what's the cause of the problem... Unless they changed the API for everyone.

Comment: My program isnt even a selfbot and I noticed this too today. Does your issue relate to mine? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67338613/discord-py-bot-returns-blank-messages

Comment: Very interesting... So it's a change Discord did to their API, but I wouldn't have expected this to affect also normal bots. This is really annoying and I have no clue how to solve it. :(

Comment: Why did you delete your question?

Comment: It seems like its just a discord API bug or something so I dont think will there is a fix for it.

Comment: Selfbots are against Discord's Terms of Service.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I've been playing with this for the past few weeks, and using tips and ideas all over the internet, I created a patched version of Discord.py for self-bots.

It seems that you need to do couple of things to get `message.content` & `message.embeds` working again:

- Disable all Intents
- Edit the IDENTIFY packet sent to Discord

My fork does all that, as well as obfuscate the user-agent and a few other things.

Check the README for things changed + credits.

Link: [GitHub](https://github.com/dolfies/discord.py-self), [PyPi](https://pypi.org/project/discord.py-self/)

Comment: I now tried using your fork instead, and .content does work, which is great. But .author doesn't work of messages by other users anyomore!

For now I guess I will use messages from history for author for now. (Also, that Github fork seems to have issues disabled)

Comment: It works perfectly for me. What exactly are you trying to get from `message.author`? I tried `message.author`, `message.author.id`, and `message.author.avatar_url`.

Comment: Actually, nevermind. I now built your fork, and created a very simple script that just printed message.author in a non-edited on_message and it worked. Maybe it was some problem with the advanced configuration I was trying to use it before (like not using a real on_message, but a sync wrapper, etc)

Comment: FYI, I don't recommend building directly from a branch, because it's still being actively developed. If you want to build from source, build from the latest tag.

Comment: If you really just want to use discord.py, just use version `1.4.2`, which doesnt send intents and hence works

Comment: @Ceres that would (mostly) solve the `message.content` problem. However, there are other problems as the bot and client APIs are diverging quickly. Also, in my fork I've been removing everything bot-related and slowly adding undocumented client stuff.

Answer (score 7):

The answer to everyone's question:

On April 30th, 2021 discord made some change that broke receiving message content and embeds (and maybe more) on selfbots only. If you have this issue, then you're using a selfbot, which is against the discord TOS... it is also deprecated by discord.py since version 1.7 and won't receive support. You need to change to a real bot if you want support

Comment: what is d.py? Did you mean discord.py?

Comment: @TKperson, yes d.py means discord.py

Comment: Is there an alternative to monitoring text without using a library since "self-bots" are getting more strict to near extinction?

Answer (score 5):

Turns out actually it doesn't work for me too, I thought it worked
because I didn't test it before, and only used history or myself as the user.

A workaround is to use **`channel.history`** instead which returns messages that
support .content and similar.

With possibly something similar to this

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    async for message in message.channel.history(limit=1):
        print(message.content)
```

I also tried (badly) making discord.py always get it from history, and this seems to work for me. (For v1.x)

```
From cbbd51bf17bb19ea4835365e08266d06a27c1459 Mon Sep 17 00:00:00 2001
From: Example User <user@example.com>
Date: Fri, 7 May 2021 13:37:50 +0300
Subject: [PATCH] add workaround for on_message on self bots

Recently, now the messages that self bots get in events are broken.
In the case of on_message, .content and .embeds don't work.

However, this isn't the case if the message is retrieved with
channel.history()

This workarounds the issue for on_message by retrieving it from history
always

NOTE: I made the parse call async, didnt seem to break anything (yet)
---
 discord/gateway.py | 6 +++++-
 discord/state.py   | 9 ++++++++-
 2 files changed, 13 insertions(+), 2 deletions(-)

diff --git a/discord/gateway.py b/discord/gateway.py
index 210a8822..019693db 100644
--- a/discord/gateway.py
+++ b/discord/gateway.py
@@ -30,6 +30,7 @@ import concurrent.futures
 import json
 import logging
 import struct
+import inspect
 import sys
 import time
 import threading
@@ -506,7 +507,10 @@ class DiscordWebSocket:
         except KeyError:
             log.debug('Unknown event %s.', event)
         else:
-            func(data)
+            if inspect.iscoroutinefunction(func):
+                await func(data)
+            else:
+                func(data)
 
         # remove the dispatched listeners
         removed = []
diff --git a/discord/state.py b/discord/state.py
index da1212c1..7c713e39 100644
--- a/discord/state.py
+++ b/discord/state.py
@@ -485,9 +485,16 @@ class ConnectionState:
     def parse_resumed(self, data):
         self.dispatch('resumed')
 
-    def parse_message_create(self, data):
+    async def parse_message_create(self, data):
         channel, _ = self._get_guild_channel(data)
         message = Message(channel=channel, data=data, state=self)
+        # This is a workaround for messages not working on self bots
+        async for temp_msg in message.channel.history(limit=1):
+            if temp_msg.id != message.id:
+                log.warning("retrieved on_message from history is not correct one")
+                break
+            
+            message = temp_msg
         self.dispatch('message', message)
         if self._messages is not None:
             self._messages.append(message)
-- 
2.30.2
```

EDIT: see someone elses answer now instead

Comment: will this work if the chat is texting really fast? Will there be duplicated messages being logged? Is this reliable? This solution to me seems like fetching from the chat on every newly received empty messages, but what happens if 2 users sent 2 messages at the same time in the same chat?

Comment: .id still works, so you could I guess if chat really is moving that fast, fetch a higher amount of previous ones and find the correct one by id. Or just verify if the correct message was received with that. I haven't experienced issues with duplicates. And I now tried sending a lot of messages very fast as a different user, and everything seemed in the correct order and nothing missed.

Comment: Ok I guess this could be a good solution. That's +1 vote from me

Answer (score 0):

Edit the gateway.py source from the discord library and find the line:

```
if state._intents is not None:
     payload['d']['intents'] = state._intents.value
```

and change it to:

```
if state._intents is not None and self._connection.is_bot == True:
     payload['d']['intents'] = state._intents.value
```

Make sure to include "bot=False" option when calling the client.run. Having an intents option when sending the IDENTIFY payload causes user accounts to not receive message content, no matter what you set the intent value to. I hate doing this, but editing the library source to remove including the intents for non bot users is the only way I can find so you can use discord.py with a user account to view message content. The intents option is however required to be used for bot accounts.

Comment: Funnily enough, if you patch in and enable the new `message_content` intent, message content works for selfbots using discord.py v1.x again.

However, still recommend using my fork because discord.py is not meant for selfbots and is very broken for them.