# getting message from other server doesnt work discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So I have this code:

```
import discord

client = discord.Client()
token = "token"

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if (message.channel.id == "channel"):
        target_channel = client.get_channel("target")
        await target_channel.send(message.content)

client.run(token, bot=False)
```

which should basically get the messages of one server channel and send them to the other server's channel. If I write with as my user in this channel the code works perfectly fine however if someone else writes in this channel I get this error:

```
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\haide\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\haide\PycharmProjects\pythonProject13\main.py", line 12, in on_message
    await target_channel.send(message.content)
  File "C:\Users\haide\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\discord\abc.py", line 1064, in send
    data = await state.http.send_message(channel.id, content, tts=tts, embed=embed,
  File "C:\Users\haide\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 254, in request
    raise HTTPException(r, data)
discord.errors.HTTPException: 400 Bad Request (error code: 50006): Cannot send an empty message
```

Any ideas to fix that?

Comment: The error is pretty much self-explanatory.

Comment: Well the error isnt true ._. It says that it cant send an empty message but the messages which the other users are sending arent empty. As far as i know it is even not possible to send an empty message in discord

Comment: If you send an image the content is empty, are you sure the messages contain some sort of text?

Comment: yup people are also writing again and again. And everytime someone wrote something i get this error :/

Comment: Does it work when you use a bot token?

Comment: yes it does @ŁukaszKwieciński

Comment: That might be the issue. Does this answer your question? [Discord API "soft-ban" for Selfbot? It can only read its own messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67339174/discord-api-soft-ban-for-selfbot-it-can-only-read-its-own-messages)

Comment: oh god thats sad but yea it does answer my question, thanks