# discord self bot acting like it cant read messages

Tags: python, discord

this is a self bot mudae sniper for discord

i made it a while ago (like 2 months ago) then stopped using it i decided to use it again but its isn't working

it logs in but it doesn't react or print a message like it should
it acts like its not even seeing the message

there aren't any error messages

honestly no clue what im missing

imports are: `from discord.ext import commands import discord, json, asyncio, re, os`

code:

```py
from imports import *

try:
    with open("config.json", "x"): pass
    config = {"token": input("Enter discord token: "), "min": int(input("Enter minimum amount of kakera: "))}
    with open("config.json", "w") as configFile:
        configFile.write(json.dumps(config))
except:
    with open("config.json", "r") as configFile:
        config = json.loads(configFile.read())

bot = commands.Bot(">", self_bot=True)

@bot.event
async def on_connect():
    os.system("cls")
    print(f"Logged in as: {bot.user}\n")

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author.id == 488711695640821760 and message.embeds:
        if "wished" in message.content.lower():
            try:
                kakera = int(re.findall(r"\*\*([0-9]+)\*\*", message.embeds[0].description)[0])
                if kakera < config["min"]:
                    print(kakera, "is less than", config["min"])
                    return
            except Exception as e:
                return
            fails = 0
            print(f"Claiming {message.embeds[0].title} in {message.channel.guild.name}")
            while True:
                try:
                    await message.add_reaction(message.reactions[0])
                    return
                except Exception as e:
                    print(e)
                    if fails > 3:
                        break
                    await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
                    fails += 1
            print("Failed to claim")

bot.run(config["token"], bot=False)
```

Comment: Using a Self-bot is against [Discord's TOS](https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/115002192352-Automated-user-accounts-self-bots-) and is therefore not okay. Also, there have been questions similar to this, such as: [Discord API “soft-ban” for Selfbot? It can only read its own messages](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67341709/14420546)

Answer (score 2):

For some reason `.content` and `.embeds` from the message object given by `on_message` stopped working a few days ago for self bots of messages not sent by yourself.

However the messages of `channel.history` do work correctly.

A workaround would be to instead use that with a limit of 1

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    async for message in message.channel.history(limit=1):
        print(message.content)
```