# How to extract message text from discord message?

Tags: python, discord.py

I am getting the following data on `on_message()` event:

```
<Message id=863340082848596027 channel=<TextChannel id=xx name='beginners' position=22 nsfw=False news=False category_id=xx> type=<MessageType.default: 0> author=<Member id=xx name='Stormwing' discriminator='3997' bot=False nick=None guild=<Guild id=xx name='r/CryptoCurrency' shard_id=None chunked=False member_count=58816>> flags=<MessageFlags value=0>>
```

the `message.content` returns empty

All I want to fetch messages from a certain channel. The code is below:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    channel_id = 'xxx'
    print(USER_TOKEN)
    bot = commands.Bot(">>>", self_bot=True)


    @bot.event
    async def on_ready():
        print(f'Bot connected as {bot.user}')
        # for guild in bot.guilds:
        #     for channel in guild.text_channels:
        #         print(channel.id,channel)


    @bot.event
    async def on_message(message):
        print(message)


    # bot.run(USER_TOKEN, bot=False)
    print('Run')
    bot.run(USER_TOKEN, bot=False)
```

Comment: Short guess it's asyn method so you might wanna await something before you try to use it, and in the context of asynchronous and await should you pass the request into the function (well maybe you do but then the argument is poorly named)

Comment: @MarkusRosjat The message is arriving, if I print `message` it returns what I pasted above. It also shows `message.author` but not the message itself

Comment: Discord.py has disallowed `message.content` for self bots. This is because they are against the Discord TOS. You should really be using a bot user instead of a self bot.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Discord API "soft-ban" for Selfbot? It can only read its own messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67339174/discord-api-soft-ban-for-selfbot-it-can-only-read-its-own-messages)

Comment: Yes I found the issue, it was due to the lib itself. Thanks