# Discord.py Self bot

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm making a self bot and im wanting to do something. I want my bot to read an embed's description, then reply.

```
actual bot:
Field = "What color is the sky?" , Value = "1. Blue 2. Red 3. Pink"

Self Bot:
1. Blue
```

im not sure where to begin

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I totally understand what you're saying as the example is very unclear. I recommend reading [the documentations](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=#discord.Message.embeds) first. But if all you want to do if read the embed fields you could try this

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    embeds = message.embeds 
    for embed in embeds:
        print(embed.to_dict())
```

Comment: This will work for a normal bot. however self-bots have been banned from the API and they receive an empty message payload, reference: [discord API “soft-ban” for Selfbot? It can only read its own messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67339174/discord-api-soft-ban-for-selfbot-it-can-only-read-its-own-messages)

Comment: Exactly. I need a way to do it for a  self-bot, not a normal bot. I havent been able to figure it out.

Comment: Take a look at the question linked in my previous answer. As it is stated there, it's not possible to do it with a self-bot since they've been banned from the API.

Comment: i got it done. It now auto answers the questions by matching the question with an answer lol