# message.content or ctx.content not working in selfbot

Tags: python, discord.py, message

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(ctx):
    if ctx.author == client.user:
        return
  
    if client.get_guild(544102306740699136):
        channel = client.get_channel(875779623638663192)
   
    await channel.send(str(ctx.author.mention) + 'just send message in channel' + str(ctx.channel.mention) + ': ' + str(ctx.content))
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Discord API "soft-ban" for Selfbot? It can only read its own messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67339174/discord-api-soft-ban-for-selfbot-it-can-only-read-its-own-messages)

Answer (score 0):

So i just found the answer and the code is:

````
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    async for message in message.channel.history(limit=1):
     channel = client.get_channel(569791029197144073)
    await channel.send(str (message.author.mention)  +   ' je poslao/la poruku u kanalu  '   +str(message.channel.mention)+': '+str            (message.content))```
````

Answer (score -1):

You could use `ctx.message.content`:

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(ctx):

if ctx.author == client.user: 
    return

if client.get_guild(544102306740699136): 
    channel = client.get_channel(875779623638663192)
    await channel.send("Message: " + ctx.message.content)
```

More information can be found **[here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html#how-do-i-get-the-original-message)**.

Comment: This won't change a thing. This will, in fact raise an error. Since when does `on_message` take `ctx` as the argument? It's supposed to be a `discord.Message` instance, not `commands.Context`, and `discord.Message` doesn't have the `message` attribute.

Comment: Just did this but replaced `ctx` with `message` and no result its just sending Message: without `message.content`