# Discord API. Bot don't see message from other users

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to make a selfbot for Discord and cant see message content from other users.

```
async def on_message(message):
    print(f'USER - {message.author} texted - {message.content}')
```

Results if I send message in channel:

```
USER - User1 texted - Hello World!
```

If User2 printed same string, result different:

```
USER - User2 texted -
```

Why i dont see message from other users and how i can solve this problem? Can someone help me?

Comment: Self-bots are against TOS. You should use a standard bot.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Discord API "soft-ban" for Selfbot? It can only read its own messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67339174/discord-api-soft-ban-for-selfbot-it-can-only-read-its-own-messages)

Answer (score 0):

Selfbots are against ToS, but if you don't care, use [discord.py-self](https://github.com/dolfies/discord.py-self). It's the same as being a bot except some features don't work because well, only bots can use them.